# Temporal Controller for various layers

Tags: qgis, temporal-controller

I have several layers that I want to animate and display on QGIS. I have been able to animate them all using the Temporal Controller, however the issue I am having is that each layer needs different timeframes. Is there a way of setting up a specific time frame for each layer without having to manually change it on the Temporal Controller? As you can see Trip 2 and Trip 3 have different dates and time frames, but I'd like for each to be animated if displayed with their specific timeframe.

[image]
[image]